# IE6 form expanding beyond desired height

Tags: css, forms, internet-explorer-6

I have a form which has expanded beyond the desired height in IE6 only :(

Please view this fiddle for the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/fbTDZ/

I don't see an issue in other browsers.

Comment: If I recall, IE6 has a bug that automatically expands `height` of containers to fit content even when you explicitly set the `height`. I'm trying to remember if there is a fix for that, but I don't believe there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue resides in the fact that your `h3` is too wide and your `inputs` are pushed below it, which you then use relative positioning to pull them back up. Restyle the h3 to be `display: inline` or at least narrow its width and then restyle the `inputs` to not have to reposition them. That will get you toward what you seek.

Comment: Nice one.

A proper wood for the trees moment :)